# Auto-login with GUI disabled in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, password

How can I make the RPi auto-login when booted, when the GUI is disabled?

You don't have to type a password, when logging in when GUI enabled, so there is probably an easy way of disabling the password prompt in the console.

Comment: there is an easier way to do this using raspi-config
this article explains it http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html showing : 1. how to auto login to the shell prompt (using a method similar to above) 2. Run scripts at startup 3. Auto start the desktop using raspi-config

Comment: Very dangerous, I missed the bit about not having a password and seemed to have screwed up the SD card. Be warned!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**For Raspbian Wheezy:**

You should be able to edit the /etc/inittab file to enable autologin.

Find a line like this in /etc/inittab

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1
```

This starts the getty process on tty1.  You can add the getty `--autologin` option to that line:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --autologin {USERNAME} --noclear 38400 tty1
```

Replace {USERNAME} with the user you want to login.

**Note** I have not tested this, check the manpage for getty for more details.

**Update:** Raspbian Jessie uses systemd so inittab is not used.
Here is a FAQ that may help for Jessie:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_set_automatic_login_on_a_virtual_console_terminal.3F

The FAQ is for Fedora but it should be very similar on Raspbian Jessie.

**UPDATE2: The page above is now gone so here is the content from the Wayback machine:**

How do I set automatic login on a virtual console terminal?

First create a new service similar to getty@.service:

```
# cp /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service \
     /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service
# ln -s /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service \
     /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty8.service
```

then edit ExecStart, Restart and Alias values, like this:

```
...
ExecStart=-/sbin/mingetty --autologin USERNAME %I
Restart=no
...
Alias=getty.target.wants/getty@tty8.service
```

and finally reload daemon and start the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start getty@tty8.service
```

Note that if you exit tty8 session, you wont be able to use it until next reboot or manual start by systemctl, except if you leave Restart as ‘always’, but I highly recommend to avoid this according to security reasons.

Comment: I have tested it; it works fine. Also, put something in ~/.bash_profile and that will get run automatically after you are logged in.

Comment: Please update the answer! There is no `/etc/inittab` file in `raspbian jessie`.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi I have added a link that may help with Jessie.

Comment: No, I still get the login prompt upon boot.

Comment: The Raspbian Jessie solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with Jessie Lite:

```
sudo -i
mkdir -pv /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
```

contents:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

only catch is that I can't logon using SSH anymore - access denied. :-(

Comment: A good answer should give an indication as to why it works. What do the those two steps do? Can you really say it works if it breaks SSH?

Comment: This doesn't work!  Still forces me to login at command line.

Comment: does using $TERM work for you?  
`ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I $TERM`

Answer (score 1):

`lightdm.conf` method didn't work for me. After a bit of playing around the easiest method I found was below.

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/
```

From there type: `ls`

You will see an `autologin@.service`

just `sudo nano autologin@.service`

and change line

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear % I $TERM
```

to

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin [Username] --noclear % I $TERM
```

Where [Username] is put the user you wish to login without the brackets.

Now I did have pi auto login working using the `raspi-config` setup, but used the above method to change the autologin for a new user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want auto-login to Raspberry Pi on Serial line,
you need to edit the /etc/inittab file on pi with sudo permissions.

Find a line like this in /etc/inittab

```
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

Add the getty --autologin option to that line.

```
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty --autologin {username} -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

Save and Reboot.

Comment: What is `T0:23`??  I thought it should be `1:2345`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running NOOBS and had a slightly different inittab file. Here's what I changed that combined both the "--autologin" on the T0 line and the 1:2345 line:

```
#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1"
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 <dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty --autologin pi - L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```