# How to enable auto-login?

Tags: raspi-config

So I just installed raspbian jessie lite on my pi 2. But I can't get it to login automatically. I first tried with raspi-config, which didn't work. Then after googling a bit, I found a tutorial which I'm suppose to edit `inittab` but when I try to access it, it's empty.

Comment: If you select the right option in raspi-config it should work. Anything using `inittab` won't. Indeed most of the tutorials before mid 2015 (and many after) are for SysV and won't work. Some will actually interfere with normal operation.

Comment: I have the same Rasbian Jessie on a Ras Pi 2. Try [THIS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/auto-login-with-gui-disabled-in-raspbian) (solution via raspberrypi.stackexchange) will probably help! Good luck

Comment: @Milliways I have tried going into raspi-config, and changed the boot option to, console autologin but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 40):

I found a solution that uses raspi-config.
I played around with it for a bit, and found something (NOTE: You may need to update raspi-config)

To enable Auto-login with raspi-config:

```
Run: sudo raspi-config
Choose option: 1 System Options
Choose option: S5 Boot / Auto Login
Choose option: B2 Console Autologin
Select Finish, and reboot the Raspberry Pi.
```

You should then be logged in automatically on every reboot. It's as easy as pi! :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked perfectly.

Comment: For me it was: 1 System Options -> S5 Boot / Auto Login -> B2 Console Autologin

Comment: Yup! This is it. Came here from Google. Still working 2023.

Answer (score 9):

I needed to know how to do this manually, not using `raspi-config`. I couldn't find anyone sharing the secret sauce. Thank Stallman for open source. Just read the [source](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config).

```bash
do_boot_behaviour() {
  if [ "$INTERACTIVE" = True ]; then
    BOOTOPT=$(whiptail --title "Raspberry Pi Software Configuration Tool (raspi-config)" --menu "Boot Options" $WT_HEIGHT $WT_WIDTH $WT_MENU_HEIGHT \
      "B1 Console" "Text console, requiring user to login" \
      "B2 Console Autologin" "Text console, automatically logged in as '$USER' user" \
      "B3 Desktop" "Desktop GUI, requiring user to login" \
      "B4 Desktop Autologin" "Desktop GUI, automatically logged in as '$USER' user" \
      3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
  else
    BOOTOPT=$1
    true
  fi
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    case "$BOOTOPT" in
      B1*)
        systemctl set-default multi-user.target
        ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
        rm -f /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
        ;;
      B2*)
        systemctl set-default multi-user.target
        ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
        cat > /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf << EOF
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin $USER --noclear %I \$TERM
EOF
        ;;
      B3*)
        if [ -e /etc/init.d/lightdm ]; then
          systemctl set-default graphical.target
          ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
          rm -f /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
          sed /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf -i -e "s/^autologin-user=.*/#autologin-user=/"
          disable_raspi_config_at_boot
        else
          whiptail --msgbox "Do 'sudo apt-get install lightdm' to allow configuration of boot to desktop" 20 60 2
          return 1
        fi
        ;;
      B4*)
        if [ -e /etc/init.d/lightdm ]; then
          systemctl set-default graphical.target
          ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
          cat > /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf << EOF
```

What I learned from this is that my changes to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` were not affecting my autologin as expected because I was missing a file called `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf`

The critical missing step is this one:

```bash
cat > /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf << EOF
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin $USER --noclear %I \$TERM
EOF
```

Which will be set to the username that `raspi-config` wants, not the one that you want. So you have to change the `$USER` in `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf` to match the username you are setting in the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` parameter `autologin-user`

Answer (score 4):

First create a new service similar to getty@.service:

```
# cp /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service \
     /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service 

# ln -s /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service \
        /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty8.service
```

then edit ExecStart, Restart and Alias values, like this:

```
...
ExecStart=-/sbin/mingetty --autologin USERNAME %I
Restart=no
...
Alias=getty.target.wants/getty@tty8.service
```

and finally reload daemon and start the service:

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start getty@tty8.service

Note that if you exit tty8 session, you wont be able to use it until next reboot or manual start by systemctl, except if you leave Restart as ‘always’, but I highly recommend to avoid this according to security reasons.

---

[source: fedoraproject.org/wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_set_automatic_login_on_a_virtual_console_terminal.3F)

Comment: This solution didn't work at all.

Comment: it doesn't work if you blindly copy paste it, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way I have found using Raspbian, is to edit the raspi-config file. Do this by opening `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and setting the `autologin-user=` parameter.

Change: `autologin-user=pi` to `autologin-user=username` where `username` is your username.

Comment: Since when did `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.con` [sic] became "the raspi-config file"? Never mind that there's simply no such file in the first place on Raspbian **lite**.